# Why are my files being automatically hidden? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

Any file or folder with the names 'a' or 'ab' on my computer instantly get hidden. I've enabled viewing hidden files and folders, and I'm also able to view superhidden system files. However these a and ab folders are not visible unless I view them from a linux boot disk, safe mode, and powertool x64 is also actually able to see them. This phenomenon is preventing me from installing a game (Aion) because the installer needs to create a folder called 'ab' for textures, but upon doing so it is instantly hidden and that throws the installer an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try and use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see if you can see what application that does this.

- Start procmon and accept the EULA (on first run only) and the UAC prompt
- Add a filter for a specific file (example: `c:\ab.txt`)
  [image: Procmon filter]
- Press `Add` and `OK` and it will show all operations on that file
- Now create the file and see what happens

It sound like you might have malware, so I would recommend a full antivirus scan with a live boot disk.